# Can FullCalendar library used with Flutter?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to use Fullcalendar (fullcalendar.io) inside a Flutter app?

There is no good calendar plugin for Flutter so I was thinking if there is a way to "combine" both worlds. Probably it can be done with some kind of wrapper?
Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use it inside a **WebView** - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#0 . As an alternative, look at SyncFusion's **SfCalendar**, available for Flutter - https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/getting-started